# +/- and root buttons in a calculator app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator app and someone suggested the following code for the basic operations (addition, subtraction...);

```
         if ([operand isEqualToString:@"+"])
           lastKnownValue += currentValue;

    else if ([operand isEqualToString:@"-"])
           lastKnownValue -= currentValue;

    else if ([operand isEqualToString:@"X"])
           lastKnownValue *= currentValue;

    else if ([operand isEqualToString:@"/"])
```

where

```
         lastKnownValue
```

is used for saving the input number before an operand is used and

```
         currentValue
```

displays the lastKnownValue on screen.
(The operations are separate buttons.)

It does work but how would I make buttons for operations such as +/-, root, square,... that do not require entering a second number or tapping the "EQUALS" button?

Comment: Please give a bit mores context to your code.  Is it executed on a button or what?  What is lastKnownValue and currentValue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do the operation on the currentvalue, and then update currentValue with the result, and refresh the display. Set lastknownValue to nil.

EDIT:

```
self.currentvalue = sqrt(current value);
self.lastknownValue = nil
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```